# Prob. 13, Sec. 18, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: If $Y$ is Hausdorff,then there is a unique extension of every continuous function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Here is Prob. 13, Sec. 18, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $A \subset X$; let $f \colon A \to Y$ be continuous; let $Y$ be Hausdorff. Show that if $f$ may be extended to a continuous function $g \colon \overline{A} \to Y$, then $g$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

My Attempt:

> Suppose that there are continuous functions $g \colon \overline{A} \to Y$ and $h \colon \overline{A} \to Y$ such that $g(a) = h(a) = f(a)$ for all $a \in A$.
>
> If there is some point $x \in \overline{A}$ for which $g(x) \neq h(x)$, then since $Y$ is Hausdorff, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ such that $g(x) \in U$ and $h(x) \in V$.
>
> Now as $g$ and $h$ are continuous (by our supposition) and as $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $Y$, so $g^{-1}(U)$ and $h^{-1}(V)$ are open sets in $\overline{A}$ in the subspace topology. So there are open sets $U^\prime$ and $V^\prime$ in $X$ such that $g^{-1}(U) = \overline{A} \cap U^\prime$ and $h^{-1}(V) = \overline{A} \cap V^\prime$.
>
> Moreover, as $x \in \overline{A}$ such that $g(x) \in U$ and $h(x) \in V$, so $x \in g^{-1}(U)$ and $x \in h^{-1}(V)$, which implies that  $x \in U^\prime \cap V^\prime$.
>
> Now as $x \in \overline{A}$ and as $U^\prime \cap V^\prime$ is an open set containing $x$, so there is an element $a \in A$ such that $a \in U^\prime \cap V^\prime$. And, as this $a \in A$, so $g(a) = h(a) = f(a)$, and also $a \in \overline{A}$.
>
> Thus $a \in \overline{A} \cap U^\prime =  g^{-1}(U)$ and $a \in \overline{A} \cap V^\prime   = h^{-1}(V)$. Therefore, $g(a) \in U$ and $h(a) \in V$.
>
> But $g(a) = h(a) = f(a)$. So $f(a) \in U \cap V$, which contradicts our choice of $U$ and $V$ as disjoint open sets containing $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, respectively.
>
> Thus there is no point $x \in \overline{A}$ for which $g(x) \neq h(x)$. That is, $g(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \in \overline{A}$. Hence $g = h$, as required.

Are there any issues with this proof?

Comment: If you don't have any concrete questions about your proof, it is better to post it as an answer to your own question. The problem is that far too many "check my proof" posts wind up with stupid "everything's fine" solutions. You will get feedback on a self-solution as easily as on a "proof-verification. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is actually simpler than this.

If $f$ and $g$ continuously extend function $f$ such that $g(x) \neq h(x)$ for some point $x \in \overline A-A$, then we can find two disjoint open sets $U, V$ such that $g(x) \in U$ and $h(x) \in V$.

In this case $g^{-1}(U)$ and $h^{-1}(V)$ are open and both contain $x$, and $g^{-1}(U) \cap h^{-1}(V)$ is open. Since $x \in \overline A$, $\exists a \in A \cap g^{-1}(U) \cap h^{-1}(V)$. But then $g(a)=h(a)$, which contradicts the disjunction of $U$ and $V$.